# Use true color for tmux window decorations

Tags: shell, tmux

Tmux gained support for displaying true color in version 2.2.  Is there anyway to use true-color for the tmux window decorations?  For example:

```
set -g window-active-style 'bg=#ffeedd'
```

Currently, tmux will pick the nearest color from a 256 color palette instead of the specified color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ability is present in Tmux source as of 2016-07-14.  See https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/490

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/427b8204268af5548d09b830e101c59daa095df9) commit explains your problem pretty much. To fix your problem you can do the following in your `.tmux.conf`:

`set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"`

You may have to change `xtemr-256color` a bit, to match the terminal you're using.

Comment: I have true color working in the terminal by using that command but tmux doesn't seem to support using true color for tmux-internal things.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info for @sascha answer above, I added `set-option -sa terminal-overrides ',xterm-256color:RGB'` to `.tmux.conf` but it still doesn't work with true color. My outside terminal is Konsole and `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`.

Eventually I set `set-option -sa terminal-overrides ',*:RGB'` and it works.